# Dynamic Attributes with Spring Data Rest Projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Let's say I start with an entity with a few fields and a map that represents dynamic attributes.  It looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id 
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private Map<String, String> attributes;
}
```

I'd like to create a Spring Data Rest projection where those dynamic attributes are first level properties of the resulting JSON object right along side the the class properties.  As an example, if *Item* had a name value of "Product A" and the attributes map contained the two entries "color" -> "red" and "size" -> "20x10", the resulting json object might look like the following.

```
{
  name: "Product A",
  color: "red",
  size: "20x10"
}
```

I'm doubting this is possible and I know I could accomplish what I want by returning a Map with a custom method on a BasePathAwareController but I thought a projection would be cleaner.

Comment: Could be a projection inside projection a solution? Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995744/java-spring-projection-inside-projection

Comment: I think Jackson's [JsonAnyGetter](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonanygetter-and-jsonanysetter-example) is what your looking for.